# Custom Profiler with .NET Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, profiling

I've written a custom profiler that I can use to profile a .NET application. However it only works with standalone .NET executables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/setting-up-a-profiling-environment

I'm wondering if there is a way to use a custom profiler for a .NET web application? I can't see to find any instructions on how to use one.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On profiler level, there is no difference between web application and desktop application.

If you run your .Net framework application through the IIS and want to profile the application, you need to add `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1` and `COR_PROFILER={CLSID}` variables to the environment variables of IIS services.

Set the profiler variables to `W3SVC` and `WAS` services. It can be added through the registry - add it to `Environment` key of `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC` or `\WAS`.

Don't forget to run `iisreset` command after the changes.